# How to limit infinitely growing pgbouncer logfile?

Tags: pgbouncer

My pgbouncer.log grows endlessly. How do I enable filename rollover or limit the logfile size for pgbouncer (Windows) ?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: No, but meanwhile we also stopped using PG SQL.

Comment: pgbouncer itself doesn't contain logrotation features I've found out. One can use logrotate to do it, however I'm still tinkering around with that. It's work in progress.